# Handling environment variables in a MERN stack with ReactJS and Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, mern

I have a mern website and now I want to host it but I have seen that you must not put .env on repository but without env my website will not run what should I do. I am going to host it on hostinger

I am confused and don't know what to do

Comment: You set the _actual environment variables_ instead, read the docs for your platform e.g. https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/linux-environment-variables-how-to-read-and-set-on-a-linux-vps/

Comment: Just create a `.env` file on the server on which you will run the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a .env file to store your important stuff. The .env file is a convenient way to store environment-specific variables, such as API keys and database passwords, in a simple text file.

Think of your mongodb url. You can simply store this on a environment variable (MONGODB_URL) and store inside the .env file. When you trying to establish the connection with mongodb, you simply have to replace your mongodb url with `process.env.MONGODB_URL`. (The process.env object is a global object that contains all of the environment variables that were set when the Node.js process was started. )

When you upload your code to github repo, you can simply add .env to the .gitignore file. So no-one can access your confidential stuff.

I hope this helps. Thank you!